# Where is the "polynomial-ness" used in Gauss' lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I stumbled upon [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/688369/673223) slick proof of Gauss lemma.

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Call a polynomial $f\in A[x]$ primitive iff the ideal generated by its coefficients is the entire $A$. Let $f, g\in A$ be primitive. Then $fg$ is primitive too.

I regurgitate the proof:

***Proof.*** Suppose not. Then the ideal generated by the coefficients of $fg$ is proper. Since $A$ has identity, we can apply Zorn's lemma and find a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ that contains all the coefficients of $fg$. Since $A$ is commutative too, $\mathfrak m$ is prime as well, and hence, $A/\mathfrak m$ an integral domain. Now, we view the coefficients of polynomials in $A[x]$ as the members of $A/\mathfrak m$. Then, $fg = 0$, but $f, g\ne 0$, which violates the integral domain-ness of $A/\mathfrak m[x]$. (For if $f = 0$, then all the coefficients of $f$ would be in $\mathfrak m$, and since $f$ is primitive, $1\in\mathfrak m$, violating the maximality. Similarly, $g\ne 0$.)

**Question:** It appears as though the definition of polynomial multiplication is nowhere being used in the proof, which is quite counterintuitive!–for we are making a comment about the *coefficients* of $fg$, which are evaluated from those of $f$ and $g$ by *polynomial multiplication*.

One way that the definition of polynomial multiplication **is** seeping in is due to the usage of the fact that $R[x]$ is an integral domain if $R$ is one. But this seems to be like a "very little" part of the much more mouthful definition of polynomial multiplication.

Can you spot something?

Comment: Polynomial multiplication seeps in via use of lead coefficient map is multiplicative  $\ell(fg) = \ell(f)\ell(g),\,$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/801791/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Yea, I noted that. But as I say, polynomial multiplication seems to be much more than just the multiplicativity of the leading coefficients. Or is it not?

Comment: Where did you note that? Are you familiar with [graded rings?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring)

Comment: @BillDubuque In stating in the last paragraph that polynomial multiplication seeps in due to this fact: $R$ is an integral domain $\implies$ $R[x]$ is an integral domain. And no, I am not familiar with graded rings, why?

Comment: There are *many* directions one can pursue toward better understanding Gauss's Lemma. A good place to start chasing links is the survey by D.D. Anderson cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2974861/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Does my answer make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

I have got an answer to my question:

In reasoning inside $A/\mathfrak m[x]$, how do we know that the product of the images of $f$, $g$ (which are polynomials in $A[x]$) is actually the image of the product of $fg$? Well this rests on the fact for any rings $R$, $S$, if $\phi\colon R\to S$ is a homomorphism, then the map $R[x]\to S[x]$ given by
$$
a_0 + \cdots + a_n x^n\mapsto \phi(a_0) + \cdots + \phi(a_n) x^n
$$
is also a homomorphism. And showing this fact requires the full-blown definition of polynomial multiplication!